# mongodb collection not found in nodejs mongo module

Tags: node.js

## Overview

I read from a .csv file, convert to JSON. Then I call my mongoinsert() function and insert that JSON data into mongodb

```
    function clean(){
      var options = {
        delimiter:',',
        quote:'"'
      };
      var data = fs.readFile('st.csv','utf8',function(err,data){
        objectArray=csvjson.toObject(data,options);
        mongoInsert();
      });
    }
    clean();
```

## mongoinsert()

is my function to which I connect to mongodb; here is where I run into a problem

```
    function mongoInsert(){
      var url = "mongodb://localhost:9999/test";
      console.log("insert function");
      MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
        db.collection('people').insertOne({'name':'jc'});
      });
    }
```

Note: I'm passing {'name':'jc'} for testing

#### sending error: 'type error db.collection is not a function'

I've printed out the the db object itself but it seems that the collection method does not exist. I'm wondering if it's node's asynchronous model, I'm just implementing it incorrectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [db.collection is not a function when using MongoClient v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662220/db-collection-is-not-a-function-when-using-mongoclient-v3-0)

Comment: You can either downgrade to v2.X or change the syntax as I mention in the second answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much!