# db.collection is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to simply insert an entry in a `MongoDB` collection using `Nodejs`. Here is my code:

**code:**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp', (err, db) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB server');
  }
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB server');

  db.collection('Todos').insertOne({
    text: 'Something to do',
    completed: false
  }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Unable to insert todo', err);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.ops, undefined, 2));
  });

  db.close();
});
```

When I run the code, it showing the following error:

**error:**

```
TypeError: db.collection is not a function
```

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662220/db-collection-is-not-a-function-when-using-mongoclient-v3-0?rq=1

Comment: Which version of Mongo you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [db.collection is not a function when using MongoClient v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662220/db-collection-is-not-a-function-when-using-mongoclient-v3-0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uninstalling existing mongodb package and reinstalling using the following commands resolved the issues

```
npm uninstall mongodb --save
npm install mongodb@2.2.33 --save
```

Version MongoDB >= 3  - That database variable is actually the parent object of the object you are trying to access. If u using mongo 3+:

```
const myDb = db.db('YourDatabase') 
myDb.collection('YourDatabase).insertOne ....
```

Answer (score 2):

you can rewrite your code as follow

```
MongoClient.connect(url,(err,db) =>{ 
  const database= db.db('TodoApp')
  database.collection('Todos').insertOne({})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is the version of the NodeJs Driver. **TypeError: db.collection is not a function.**   If the version is > 3.0.1 then you have to change the db to client. For more info check this page, it helped me!
[[db.collection is not a function when using MongoClient v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662220/db-collection-is-not-a-function-when-using-mongoclient-v3-0][1])

Hope that helps!