# MongoDB error while retrieving collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having a problem getting collection from the database in my Node.js application. I'm using Mongodb 3.6.

That's how I set it up:

```
var moment                  = require('moment');
var MongoClient             = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

/*
  ===========================================================================
                DB setup
  ===========================================================================
*/


var state = {
  db: null,
}

function get() {
    return state.db;
}

exports.connect_database = function(done) {
    if (state.db) return done()
    MongoClient.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, db) {
        if (err) return done(err)
        state.db = db
        done()
    })
}
/* some other functions ... */

exports.return_collection = function(collection_name, callback) {
    var result_array = [];
    var collection = get().getCollection(collection_name);

    var result = collection.find()
    result.forEach(function(res) {
        result_array.push(res);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("error: ")
        console.log(error);
        if (!error)
            callback(result_array);
    });
}
```

In the main file I do:

```
'use strict';

// LIB IMPORTS
var env                     = require('node-env-file');
env(__dirname + '/.env');

// LOCAL IMPORTS
var aux                     = require('./modules/aux.js');
var scheduler               = require('./modules/scheduler.js');
var Bot                     = require('./modules/bot.js');

/*
  ===========================================================================
                DB setup
  ===========================================================================
*/

aux.connect_database((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to Mongo.')
        process.exit(1)
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to db.');
    }
})
```

I can see in the log the `Connected to db.` prompt, so the connection works fine. After that I try to call some function to add/retrieve data from the db and i get the error:

```
TypeError: get(...).getCollection is not a function
    at Object.exports.return_collection
```

If I try to print the state.db variable I get the following result:

```
MongoClient {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  s:
   { url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/BotDb',
     options:
      { socketOptions: {},
        read_preference_tags: null,
        readPreference: [Object],
        dbName: 'slackBotDb',
        servers: [Object],
        server_options: [Object],
        db_options: [Object],
        rs_options: [Object],
        mongos_options: [Object],
        socketTimeoutMS: 360000,
        connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise] },
     promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
     dbCache: {},
     sessions: [] },
  topology:
   Server {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { serverOpening: [Function],
        serverDescriptionChanged: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatStarted: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatSucceeded: [Function],
        serverHeartbeatFailed: [Function],
        serverClosed: [Function],
        topologyOpening: [Function],
        topologyClosed: [Function],
        topologyDescriptionChanged: [Function],
        joined: [Function],
        left: [Function],
        ping: [Function],
        ha: [Function],
        authenticated: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        close: [Function],
        parseError: [Function],
        open: [Object],
        fullsetup: [Object],
        all: [Object],
        reconnect: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 22,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     clientInfo:
      { driver: [Object],
        os: [Object],
        platform: 'Node.js v7.10.0, LE' },
     s:
      { coreTopology: [Object],
        sCapabilities: null,
        clonedOptions: [Object],
        reconnect: true,
        emitError: true,
        poolSize: 5,
        storeOptions: [Object],
        store: [Object],
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        options: [Object],
        sessionPool: [Object],
        promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise] } } }
```

What am I missing? In the mongo console everything looks fine:

```
> db.getCollection("users");
BotDb.users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any function named `getCollection` in the [API documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/) for the Node.js MongoDB native driver. Collections are usually fetched with [`collection('mycoll')`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Db.html#collection). So you can rewrite this line:

```
var collection = get().getCollection(collection_name);
```

to

```
var collection = get().collection(collection_name);
```

Note that if you use v3.0 or later of the driver you have to modify the connect function as well. There were some changes done to the connection functions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47662979/8574934)). The callback now returns a client object rather than the db object. So you'll have to change your function to:

```
exports.connect_database = function(done) {
    if (state.db) return done()
    MongoClient.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        state.db = client.db('database_name');
        done();
    })
}
```

Note the `'database_name'` string. It should be the name of your database.

Comment: That was it, I upgraded Mongo v3.0 and I wasn't importing the client db correctly! Thanks