# TypeError: db.collection is not a function with user password restriction

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a university project where I can ssh to a server that has a mongodb with fixed database/username/password. I imported a collection and now want to read it out with nodejs for testing. After starting it with node server.js it returns "Connected correctly to server" into console but then I get a TypeError: db.collection is not a function

What is wrong? Thanks

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const user = encodeURIComponent('x');
const password = encodeURIComponent('y');
const authMechanism = 'DEFAULT';

// Connection URL
const url = `mongodb://${user}:${password}@localhost:27017/database?authMechanism=${authMechanism}`;


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

    console.log("Connected correctly to server");//works

    var cursor = db.collection('locations').find();//throws error

    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {

        console.log(doc);

    });
});
```

Comment: You need to check for an error first. Before your `console.log()`, you should check for `err` being not null.

Comment: How can I do that? if(!err) { console.log(...); } else { console.log(err);} ?

Comment: Don't post here, try the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const user = encodeURIComponent('x');
const password = encodeURIComponent('y');
const authMechanism = 'DEFAULT';

// Connection URL
const url = `mongodb://${user}:${password}@localhost:27017/database?authMechanism=${authMechanism}`;


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if(err){
        console.log("Connection failed");
    }
    else{

        console.log("Connected correctly to server");

        var cursor = db.collection('locations');//same error

        cursor.find({}).toArray(function(err,docs){
            if(err){
                console.log("did'nt find any!")
            }
            else{
                console.log(docs)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: two times console.log("did'nt find any!") . What should be in the second else

Comment: 2nd else will show the response it got from the database

Comment: I fixed your code and still get the same TypeError: db.collection is not a function

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662220/db-collection-is-not-a-function-when-using-mongocl

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after all:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const user = encodeURIComponent('x');
const password = encodeURIComponent('y');
const authMechanism = 'DEFAULT';

// Connection URL with and without authentication
const url = `mongodb://${user}:${password}@localhost:27017/database?authMechanism=${authMechanism}`;
//const url = `mongodb://localhost:27017/`;

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log("connect works");

    let database = db.db('database');

    database.collection('users').find().toArray((err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        results.forEach((value)=>{
            console.log(value);
        });
    })
});
```