# How to save data into MongoDB from HTML? collection() is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, post

I am trying to practice with building a website that customers can leave their contact information and I am trying to save what users (customers) typed into MongoDB but I need some help.

So this is my connect.js file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const connect = mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/test", {useNewUrlParser: true});

module.exports = { connect };
```

And this is my app.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
let port = 3000;
let app = express();
let publicPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public");

const { connect } = require("./db/connect");
const { UserRequest } = require("./models/user_request");

app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/user-requests", (req, res) => {
  let userRequest = new UserRequest({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    mobile: req.body.mobile,
    experience: req.body.experience
  });
  connect.then((db) => {
    db.collection("user-requests").insertOne(userRequest, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
      }
      res.send(result);
    });
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

And my simple form:

```
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card text-center card-form mt-4 mb-4">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2>Contact Info</h2>
                <form id="user_input" method="POST" action="/user-requests">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="apply-form-name" id="apply-form-name" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="apply-form-email" id="apply-form-email" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="E-mail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="tel" name="apply-form-tel" id="apply-form-tel" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Mobile Phone Number" maxlength="11">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="apply-form-exp" id="apply-form-exp" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Note">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

So what I want to do is, save data that a user typed inside the form tags of HTML into MongoDB.

As you can see in the connect.js file which I tried to connect to the local MongoDB using Mongoose library, I exported MongoDB variable.

What I expected is user inputs are being saved as the Submit button is clicked on the website, but it returns an error saying:

```
(node:29016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: db.collection is not a function
    at connect.then (D:\OttoWebWorking\node.js\app.js:34:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:29016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:29016) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
with a non-zero exit code.
(node:29016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: db.collection is not a function
    at connect.then (D:\OttoWebWorking\node.js\app.js:34:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:29016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

I watched some tutorials online and thought it would be pretty simple but yeah. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the mongo DB locally on your computer?

Comment: What do you mean? I am using Robo3T and yes it works. I can connect to a local DB on the port 27017. And it is currently connected and on, if this is what you meant.

Comment: Yes, do you see a "test" database, and a collection "user-requests" ?

Comment: Also, where are you requiring the exported MongoDB? The "client" of MongoDB is generally what is used...and you're using the "promise" pattern. So you need to call something like `MongoDB.then(function(db){...`

Comment: Yeah I do. Think I have done something wrong there but cannot figure out.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662220/db-collection-is-not-a-function-when-using-mongoclient-v3-0

Comment: Oh the require line is in the app.js but I think I didn't copy and paste it. I will edit the post.

Comment: Thought it solved but it is still returning the same error after I apply the MongoDB.then(). :/