# How to connect NodeJs to an Atlas mongodb Cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm setting up a new app using an Atlas Database with node and all i get is an error saying " MongoError: MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db".

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://alberto:pass@lel-kicis.mongodb.net/test";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("students")
   .then(db => console.log('DB conectada'))
   .catch(err => console.log(error));
 });
```

Comment: You did not check `err`. There was probably an error thrown which are ignoring, and most likely due to an authentication problem or unreachable host. Also `MongoClient.connect()` is the preferred and recommended method. It returns a `Promise`, so you can do `Mongoclient.connect(uriString).then(..code..).catch(err => console.error(err));` Or even use `async/await` unless your NodeJS is older than version 8.

Comment: Specifically see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47662979/2313887) for a valid usage example. Except for the `client.close()`, which is something your application should probably **never** call. We only typically show that for short "example" listings.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are missing to initiate the mongo client.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://alberto:pass@lel-kicis.mongodb.net/test";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("students")
   .then(db => console.log('DB conectada'))
   .catch(err => console.log(error));
 });
```

**Also, Atlas generate the initial connection code block for you. Follow the below steps.**

Clck on connect button

[image]

Select Connect Your Application from the next window

[image]

On the next window, Select NodeJs as driver and select the required version. Also, select Full driver example for full code block

[image]

Now copy the code and use it directly.

Comment: I´ve done that already and it did´nt work

Comment: Did you provide the correct password in the connection string?

Comment: i´ve check again and yep, it is correct

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `mongodb` connector docs, the syntax for `MongoClient` is `new MongoClient(url, options, callback)`. The signature for the callback is `(err, client) => { //body }`.

If you don't pass in the optional callback, you get and instance of `MongoClient` (which is the case here). The `connect` method also expects the same callback signature, so your connection should be like:

```
const instance = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
// notice 'client' in the callback
instance.connect((err, client) => {
  if (err) console.log('failed to connect')
  else {
    console.log('connected')
    const collection = client.db("test").collection("students")
    ...
  }
 });
```

`mongodb` connector also support promise, so you can also do:

```
// connection is a promise
const connection = instance.connect()
connection.then((err, client) => { // etc })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mongoose and mongodb-uri :

Here is the way I initialise the connection :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uriUtil = require('mongodb-uri')

// Create a new connection
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
// mongoose.set('debug', DEBUG)

const dbURI = uriUtil.formatMongoose(process.env.MONGO_URI)

const options = {
    autoIndex: DEBUG,
    autoReconnect: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
}  

const conn = mongoose.createConnection(dbURI, options)

conn.on('open', () => console.log('DB connection open'))
conn.on('error', err => console.log(`DB connection error : ${err.message}`, err))
conn.on('close', () => console.log('DB connection closed'))

module.exports = conn
```

Using the connection string provided by mongoDb for driver node.js version 3.0 or later.