# getting error while adding data to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to add data in mongodb but getting error everytime i make a post request to api
here i share the code

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url =
  "mongodb+srv://******:***********@cluster0-bxzzc.mongodb.net/auth?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

exports.addUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url)
    .then(function(db) {
      // <- db as first argument
      db.collection("user")
        .insertOne({
          name: req.body.name,
          password:req.body.password
        })
        .then(result => {
          res.send(result.ops[0]);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.send("failure in db");
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send("error");
    });
}
```

so whenever i am making a request i am getting error in console that

> TypeError: db.collection is not a function

and also i am new to express so have i handled error correct like one catch for handling error if we get some error while adding data to mongodb and another outer catch if we have something wrong in our api

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662220/db-collection-is-not-a-function-when-using-mongoclient-v3-0